# Easiest to use connecter/interface to use MySQL / Other database with C++

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010

I apologize in advance if I'm asking a duplicate question here, but what's the easiest way to use SQL (trying MySQL right now, but I can use any relational database) and C++ together? I've tried using MySQL++, the MySQL C++ connector, but all I'm getting right now are a bunch of linker errors (I'm using Visual Studio 2010).

All I need to do are insertions after I connect to the database, so I was wondering if there was an easier solution rather than dealing with all these libraries and drivers? I'm new to C++ / Visual Studio, so pardon me if I sound like a totally beginner... I wish I could just download the JDBC driver jar file and have everything work... but sadly this ain't Java :(

Answer (score 1):

Use ODBC, which is a generic database API layer similar in function to JDBC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms710252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can get the ODBC connector for MySQL 5.1 here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html

Microsoft's ODBC implementation on Windows lets you manage drivers (connectors) and data sources through the Control Panel.

There's a good overview here: http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/working-with-odbc-from-c/